# VideoView with soundPool at single time

Tags: android, android-videoview, soundpool

How can I realize it? VideoView is working fine, but there is no sound from soundPool.

```
  soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
            soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                soundsMap.put(SOUND1, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.water1, 1));
                soundsMap.put(SOUND2, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.water2, 1));


            AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;  

            soundPool.play(SOUND1, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1);
            .
            .
            .
            VideoView.start();
```

Comment: I need to launch video and on backgroung I need to play sound, for now. Video-works, sounds - no :[

Comment: Soundpool has a limit of 1MB, is your file an audio clip?

Comment: I've tried to make a sound by clicking other Button - It was working

Answer (score 0):

```
soundPool.play(SOUND1, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1);
```

try this instead of above code

```
soundPool.play(soundsMap.get(SOUND1), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1);
```

I guess your using a map to store all your music files